# How do I order my loop query?

Tags: loop, wpdb

I have a table in my database containing vote a tally I'm trying to order posts by.

screenshot: [the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j83Xa.png)

I've tried something like this, which brings up all the voted posts and pagination okay but does not order them by DESC. Any advice if I'm approaching this right is appreciated.

```
   <?php
 global $wpdb;
$my_posts = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT like_pid FROM wp_likes_count ORDER BY like_count");
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
    'post__in' => $my_posts['like_pid'],
    'paged' => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => 6,

    'order' => 'DESC'
    );
query_posts($args); ?>


               <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>    
               <!-- do stuff -->
               <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The Problem

`$my_posts` doesn't contain any posts. It contains post IDs and likes. And you're dropping both into `post__in`, which can't work. I guess even the number of posts wouldn't work if the plugin(?) wouldn't add any post with a 0-x integer to the db-table per default.

#### The Debug

Try the following:

```
$my_likes = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT like_pid FROM wp_likes_count ORDER BY like_count DESC");
echo '<pre>';
print_r( $my_likes );
echo '</pre>';
```

which will likely show you an array containing two sub-arrays.

#### Way to a solution

Then try to get the sub-array you need and drop it into your query. *Example:* `'post__in' => $my_likes['like_pid']`.

#### The Plugin

Anyway, a plugin should store something like this in the post_meta table in a field and not add an unnecassary table for something like that. There should be a facebook plugin by otto in the wp.org repo. This one's much stronger, better written & by a trustable author. You should consider switching.

Comment: I'm only a learner so still working on your solution... it is a custom plugin with a few features unseen in others, so I'll have to have it worked on. The array I got back was `(
    [0] => 6
    [1] => 37
    [2] => 9
    [3] => 33
    [4] => 36
    [5] => 32
    [6] => 70
    [7] => 8
    [8] => 27
    [9] => 69
    [10] => 53
    [11] => 7
    [12] => 72
)` I tried to use your example code without luck, I thought maybe $my_likes['like_count'] but no.

Comment: It should be fine. You're getting back an array containing all the post IDs as values and `'post__in'` does implode the array. Could you update your Q with the *exact current* code?

Comment: @kaiser I've updated the first to what I'm trying.

Comment: and yes the array from your debug code was showing the Post ID in the correct order by amount of votes.

Comment: Could it be that you have another loop before it (it's not your main loop)?

Comment: It's the only loop on custom page template, although the theme is a modified classifieds script. I enabled a plugin to see what queries are being ran and got a few strange looking ones.
[link to screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/jJkM4.png)

Comment: [SOLVED] fixed it with a small plugin "When constructing a WordPress post query in your theme template files or plug-in, WordPress offers the option to explicitly specify the posts to retrieve using the post__in parameter. Unfortunately, the orderby parameter does not offer an option that will sort the result by the exact order passed in the post__in parameter. This plug-in adds a post__in option for the orderby parameter that will order the result by the exact order specified in the post__in parameter." http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/sort-query-by-post-in/

Answer (score 1):

User the parameter 'order' in your loop call.

```
$args = array(
    'post__in' => $my_posts,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'order' => 'DESC'
);
```

There is also a order_by parameter

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

Comment: ..No luck there, it seems to be ordering by post date no matter what I try.